# Index shape issue in Heat map in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Will appreciate if someone can fix it for me. i am creating a heat map in Python in Power Bi and I get error as Index error:inconsistent shape between the condition and the input got(7054,1) and (7054,))

here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2048,1536))
sns.heatmap(dataset['Value'], cmap= 'coolwarm')
ax.set_title('Data by Index')
plt.show()
```

My dataset has Values and Id. Values is a single column with around  1.5 million values and Id has two values repeated. its something like this :

```
Id    Value     GroupIndex
Boo11   2.5         1
Boo11   4.5         2
Boo12   3.7         1
```

In short, I would like to create a heatmap here with "Value" column

Updated code which works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(250,250))
data = np.asarray(dataset['Value']).reshape(7540,1)
sns.heatmap(data, cmap= 'coolwarm')
ax.set_title('Data by Index')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about applying reshape to the dataset?

```
dataset['Value'].reshape((7054,1))
```

But it does not seem that the error is in the part of the code that you did not paste.

Comment: Hi, I did this(see question with updated code) and it works. But now my problem is I have a slicer on Id in my Power Bi report, so if i select a different id , I get the error on heat map as cannot reshape array of size 7000 into shape (7540,1). How can i fix this? each time I cant change the dimension.

Comment: How do you expect to get 540 more elements for array of 7000? Reshaping is not going to create them. Either your calculations are wrong somewhere or you need to add sentinel values when the value cannot be calculated (the remaining 540 times).

Comment: do you have an example on how to add this sentinel values. The heatmap currently shows the value for one ID and in Power Bi we have the option to select ID and the visual renders according to that ID, so for ID A I have visual with 7540 elements but if I select ID 'B' there are 7000 elements but the visual fails. so calculation is not wrong, just that need to handle it more dynamically

Comment: In order for us to help more you must provide the snippet where the error appears with **the full stack trace**.